# Groovy : No such file or directory, when I load resource files

Tags: file, groovy, jar, resources

I get the following `Exception`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/test/untitled2/tool/build/libs/tool-1.0.jar!/datasource/reportQuery.txt (No such file or directory)
```

When I try to run `groovy` jar, using the following command

```
java -jar tool-1.0.jar
```

The code that I used to read resources file

```
String loadDataSourceByName(String name) {
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    def resource = classloader.getResource("datasource/${name}.txt")
    String fileContents = new File(resource.getFile()).getText('UTF-8')
    fileContents
}
```

project structure :

[image: project structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`classloader.getResource(..)` returns `URL`

so just apply `getText("UTF-8")` to `URL`:

```
String content = classloader.getResource("datasource/${name}.txt")?.getText("UTF-8")
```

or:

```
String content = classloader.getResourceAsStream("datasource/${name}.txt")?.getText("UTF-8")
```